# Unshortening a url using Axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I was reading how to unshorten a url with request in this article https://loige.co/unshorten-expand-short-urls-with-node-js/ and I wanted to know if it can be done in axios.

**My Attempt:**

```
 const geturl = async link => {
    const res = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: link,
      maxRedirects: 1
    });
    console.log(res.headers.Location);
  };
geturl("URL GOES HERE");
```

Far as I can see, Axios does not use headers location like request does...

Comment: can you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: It simply reasds as undefined

Comment: so the request works fine? no errors regarding a cross origin request?

Comment: it does but not for other parts of the request. Besides Reqest is depreciated and I want to assign as much data as I can under a single request rather than request for each query using a different tool. Just seems horribly inefficient.

Comment: would it be `.Location` or `.location`?

Comment: according to Guerric P bellow, it appears this syntax only works when logging errors.

Comment: so, it's `.Location` on success and `.location` on failure - didn't realise axios was so odd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `maxRedirects` to `0` then the redirection will be considered as an error and you'll be able to retrieve the `Location` header:

```
const geturl = async link => {
    try {
        return await axios({
            method: "get",
            url: link,
            maxRedirects: 0
        });
    } catch (e) {
        if (Math.trunc(e.response.status / 100) === 3) {
            console.log(e.response.headers.location);
            return geturl(e.response.headers.location);
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
};

geturl("http://google.com").then(x => x.status).then(console.log);
```

Comment: This works but then I run into a new problem.  I need the request to pass and I also want to try to return both the url and its other response data in a single request.

Comment: You would need some kind of hook, and this issue https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/932 lets us know that the library doesn't handle this. Supposing that it errors out before redirecting, that means we could trigger the second request manually without any network overhead. Do you want me to provide this kind of solution?

Comment: absolutely. I would love to see how thats pulled off

Comment: so this returns the error's message , but keeps the fetch running?

Comment: Yes this follows and `console.log` redirects (and there could be several). When there are no more redirects you get the final request.

Comment: Ill try and play with this for a bit. Thanks again!